# Uncrustify: nested block indeting is wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, formatting, code-cleanup, uncrustify

I have this code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (self.adAppearBlockIsAnimated) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationTime animations:^{
            self.adAppearBlock();
        }];
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, Uncrustify makes it look like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (self.adAppearBlockIsAnimated) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationTime animations:^{
                self.adAppearBlock();
            }];
    }
});
```

My config:

```
indent_oc_block=true
indent_oc_block_msg = 0
```

Does anyone know how to make it look normal? Without extra spaces in nested block.

EDIT: I cannot comment now, I am using xCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this a bug in Uncrustify itself;  you can't necessarily work around it with a config change.

See:

https://github.com/bengardner/uncrustify/issues/68

(Personally, I'm a big fan of turning on "tab always indents", then selecting all, hitting  and living with whatever Xcode produces.  By having a standard set of formatting defaults for our team, anyone on the team can do this and not generate a bunch of spurious diffs when committing code.)

Comment: update your Uncrustify version, and it seems solve my problem